# My BIOS is outdated. Will I be affected by Meltdown and Spectre?

Tags: windows-10, security, bios, meltdown, spectre

I had made the mistake of buying a Lenovo Laptop. The model is Lenovo Flex 2-14.
This laptop has a bios from 2014 and Lenovo never issued an update.

**I've been reading on some major sites that BIOS must also be up to date to prevent the latest Spectre and Meltdown security flaws along with Windows updates.**

*My processor is Intel Core i5-4210.*

If I just update Windows 10, is that okay or should I do anything else further to make the laptop secure. Lenovo does not officially give any BIOS update, is there any other way the board manufacture issues updates to BIOS?

Answer (score 2):

> If I just update Windows 10, is that okay or should I do anything else
> further to make the laptop secure. Lenovo does not officially give any
> BIOS update, is there any other way the board manufacture issues
> updates to BIOS?

Only `CVE-2017-5753` and `CVE-2017-5754` can be fixed with kernel changes to Windows.
`CVE-2017-5715` requires a silicon microcode update, but Intel at least initially, will only provide patches to Haswell and newer products.

> [image]

[Understanding the performance impact of Spectre and Meltdown mitigations on Windows Systems](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2018/01/09/understanding-the-performance-impact-of-spectre-and-meltdown-mitigations-on-windows-systems/)

> Intel wants to initially provide patches, only for processors released in the last five years, by the end of January.  What happens to older processors is unclear.
>
> Intel boss Brian Krzanich announced at the industry fair CES, to
> provide updates for Intel processors of the past five years, which are
> to close the security gaps Meltdown and Spectra. 90 percent of these
> processors will receive an update within the next seven days, the rest
> by the end of January.

Additionally, the software mitigations are more effective on Haswell and newer products, due to their support for PCID.

> Recent Intel processors from the generation Haswell (2013) aka Core
> i-4000 / Xeon E5 v3 have a feature called Process-Context Identifier
> (PCID), which reduces the performance penalty of the meltdown patches.
> Software activates PCID via the control register CR4 of the processor
> (PCID Enable / PCIDE). Then a 12-bit PCID can be set in CR3 to
> distinguish the memory areas of up to 4096 running processes.

Source: [Meltdown and Specter: Intel patches processors produced from 2013, confirms performance impact update](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.heise.de%2Fnewsticker%2Fmeldung%2FMeltdown-und-Spectre-Intel-patcht-ab-2013-produzierte-Prozessoren-bestaetigt-Performance-Auswirkung-3936956.html&edit-text=)

Dell will have to update a firmware update in order to update, which includes the Intel provided microcode update, otherwise, you will be at least partially vulnerable to CVE-2017-5715.